# how to show progress bar in android when moving from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

i am new in android programming and i have the requirement to fetch user the contacts and display  all them on other activity.I have done all the main functionality but there is a requirement that i want to show progress when fetching is under progress.

Comment: use Asynch task to fetch contacts or create a separete thread to get the contacts and show the progressbar on UI thread after completion of task dismiss the progress bar

Comment: here is the code i used for that is there any issue in this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271587/how-to-show-progress-in-android/15273301?noredirect=1#comment21547446_15273301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following code (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8133278/1393623)) in my apps to do what you are trying to do and it works like a charm for me.

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Long, Boolean>()
        {
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)
            {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setMax(params[0]);
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                publishProgress(0L);

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long waitTime = params[0] * 1000;
                try
                {
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < waitTime)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        publishProgress(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values)
            {
                if (values[0] == 0)
                {
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress((int) (values[0] / 1000));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
            {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        }.execute(5);
    });
```

Comment: you mean i fetch all the data on first activity and after that onPostExecute()  open it in other activity

Comment: here is the code i have tried please check once where is the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271587/how-to-show-progress-in-android/15278479?noredirect=1#15278479

Comment: I think you have already found the answer in the accepted solution in the other question. Good luck! :)